# LINQ - get max number to insert a new record

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I think Im tying myself up in knots with this and I assume there's a nicer way to do this.

Im using LINQ to insert a new record to a table,  all Im putting in at this point is one field, Case_number, the key field is an autogenrated int.

Each record contains an area number along with the case number, and due to multiple db's being merged (not my doing!) I can have area 1, case_no 1, case_no 2, area 2 case_no 1, case_no2 etc.

So what I need to do is get the max case_no where the area = what I pass in.
can this be done in the one public void, something like (and I know this is not correct):

```
    ASB_DataDataContext iC = new ASB_DataDataContext();
    Input iInput = new Input();
    iInput.Case_No = Max of case no where area = 1
    iC.Inputs.InsertOnSubmit(iInput);
    iC.SubmitChanges();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
iInput.Case_No = iC.Inputs.Max(x => Case_No)
```

and also

```
iInput.Case_No = iC.Inputs
                   .Where(area == 1)
                   .Max(x => x.Case_No)
```

Comment: this works too var item = iInput.NRT_No = iC.Inputts.Max(x => x.Case_No);

Comment: Yes, absolutely and you can obviously use where condition too.

Comment: excellent, didnt realise you could put the WHERE condition in there, very handy